# Ansible - set a fact from dynamic variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I call specific variables file from a fact

```
- name: Load vars - {{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }} package list
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ ansible_distribution | lower }}-pkglist.yml"
  # if vars file is not found we continue
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Variables in that file could have different name, depending of the distribution

```
#package for all debians server
prefix_debian:  
- pkgname
- pkgname
...

#package for all debian 10 server
prefix_10 :
- specific major version pkgname
- specific major version pkgname
- specific major version pkgname
...
```

I also have a 'common' package list which is used for all linux distrib

I need to concat these 3 different list the the package list that have to be install on the host

common_pkg_list + {{ ansible_ distribution }}-pkglist + {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}-pkglist

To achieve that I tried to setfact for each list from the dynamics variable name:

```
-name:
  set_fact:
    common_pkg: "{{ prefix_commonpkglist }}"
    ditro_pkg: "prefix_{{ ansible_distribution | lower }}"
    version_pkg: "prefix_{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}"
```

But after the sefact, the list is lost...

How can I set my dynamic(variables) list name as a fact ?

Comment: => `"{{ base_pkg_list + lookup('vars', ansible_distribution + '-pkglist') + lookup('vars', ansible_distribution_major_version + '-pkglist') }}"`

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

Here the final set_fact I used:

```
- name: Building package list for {{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}
  set_fact:
    common_pkg: "{{ prefix_commonpkglist }}"
    ditro_pkg: "{{ lookup('vars', 'prefix_' + ansible_distribution | lower) }}"
    version_pkg: "{{ lookup('vars','prefix_' + ansible_distribution_major_version) }}"

- name: Installing packages
  package:
    name: "{{ common_pkg + ditro_pkg + version_pkg }}"
    state: present
```